# Rails getting form value to create method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb, ruby-on-rails-4

I am creating a form which allows a User to send another User an email without actually seeing their email address.

I am using this gem: https://github.com/plataformatec/mail_form to handle this.

Currently I am very close to getting things working. I have my app emailing the correct person and giving the correct reply information. However, I cannot get the message body to appear.

My view form. (emails/new.html.erb)

```
<h1>Mail#new</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/mail/new.html.erb</p>


 <%= form_for @email do |f| %>

      <%= f.label :message, 'Message:' %> 
      <%= f.text_area :message %>

      <%= f.submit "Send Message" %>
    <% end %>
```

my controller (emails_controller.rb)

class EmailsController < ApplicationController

def new
    @email = Email.new
    flash[:userid] = params[:id]

end

```
  def create
    @touser = User.find(flash[:userid])
    @fromuser = User.find(current_user.id.to_i)
    @email = Email.new(:name => @fromuser.name, :email => @fromuser.email, :message => params[:message], :to => @touser.email)

    if @email.deliver
        flash.now[:notice] = 'Thank you for your message!'
    else
        render :new
    end

  end

end
```

So using params[:message] does not work. How Can I access the :message data which I collect with my view?

Comment: if you are using form_for @email, the message will be in params[:email][:message]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are using form_for @email, the message will be in params[:email][:message]